# Javascript RegExp replace. How to carry unknown characters into replacement?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to get a much deeper understanding of JS RegExp for a project I'm working on.

So if I were checking for all strings containing `foo` and then a character that is not a number, I would use `/foo[^0-9]/`. However, let's say I want to change all strings matching that pattern to `foobar` and then the original characters, how would I go about that?

```
str = foozip;
newStr = str.replace(/foo[^0-9]/, "foobar");
console.log(newStr);
//returns foobarip Note the lack of a z.

str = foozip;
newStr = str.replace(/foo/, "foobar");
console.log(newStr);
//this matches foo6zip, which is no good
```

Do I have to run a separate check to do this? Is there a way to carry unknown characters from one side of a replace to the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use lookahead:

   ```
   str.replace(/foo(?=[^0-9])/, "foobar")
   ```
2. Use capture groups:

   ```
   str.replace(/foo([^0-9])/, "foobar$1")
   ```